# How to excludes my visits from Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-sites

I have integrated Google Sites website with Google Analytics and I access the website frequently to add more content. I want Google Analytics to track visits from real visitors only. How can I configure it to exclude or filter out my visits?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you exclude yourself from Google Analytics on your website using cookies?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15552/how-do-you-exclude-yourself-from-google-analytics-on-your-website-using-cookies)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [Google Analytics opt out browser add-on](http://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout).

You can also block your own IP address. [Source](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55481)

> If you want to exclude internal traffic from appearing in your reports, you can filter out a specific IP address or a range of IP addresses. You can also use cookies to filter out visits from particular users. We'll explain how below. 
>   To exclude by IP address:
>
> 1. Click **Filter Manager** from the Analytics Settings page
> 2. Enter a **Filter Name** for this filter
> 3. From the **Filter Type** drop-down list, select **Exclude all traffic from an IP address**
> 4. The **IP address** field will auto-populate with an example IP address. Enter the correct value. Remember to use regular expressions when entering any IP address. For example, if the IP address to filter is:
>
>    176.168.1.1
>      then the **IP address** value will be:
>      176.168.1.1
>
>    You may also enter a range of IP addresses. For example: 
>      **Range**: 176.168.1.1-25 and 10.0.0.1-14
>      **IP address** value : ^176.168.1.([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])$|^10.0.0.([1-9]|1[0-4])$
>
>    For help finding the correct expression for your range of IP addresses, use our tool:
>      http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55572
> 5. Select the profiles to which this filter should be applied in the **Available Website Profiles** box
> 6. Click Add to move the selected profiles into the **Selected Website Profiles** list
> 7. Click **Finish** to save this filter, or **Cancel** to return to the previous page

You can also block yourself with a cookie

> **To exclude traffic by Cookie Content**
>
> **Note**: This is an advanced alternative to the previous method.
>
> To exclude traffic from dynamic IP addresses, you can use a JavaScript function to set a cookie on your internal computers. You will then be able to filter all visitors who have this cookie from appearing on your Analytics reports.
>
> How to exclude traffic by cookie:
>
> 1. Create a new page on your domain, containing the following code:
>
>    `<body onLoad="javascript:pageTracker._setVar('test_value');">`
>
>    (Please note that this code is in addition to the Google Analytics tracking code that you have on every page of your website.)
> 2. In order to set the cookie, visit your newly created page from all computers that you would like to exclude from your reports.
> 3. Create an Exclude filter to remove data from visitors with this cookie. Follow these instructions http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55494
>      to create a filter with the following settings:
>
> Filter Type: Custom filter > Exclude
>   Filter Field: User Defined
>   Filter Pattern: test_value
>   Case Sensitive: No

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think the only thing that should work is the browser add-on because JavaScript is not allowed in Google Sites. However the add-on acts on all websites not just my site and there is no way to configure it. For the time being I will install it on FF and use it for edits and use Chrome for my ordinary browsing. This should do the trick.

Comment: And if you delete browser cookies will the plugin still work???

Comment: John, you might want to put the HTML in point 1 of the *Cookie* solution in back-ticks, so it actually is visible.

Answer (score 0):

The forum here http://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/analytics/NTHhcXNvE3A says that the JavaScript above does not work with the new asynchronous code and gives some additional information on setting a cookie.

Comment: The link is broken.