# Google Analytics: Block Your Dynamic IP Visits?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a dynamic IP, which doesn't work for Google Analytics IP filtering.  I read this post 
[How to excludes my visits from Google Analytics?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16507/how-to-excludes-my-visits-from-google-analytics) but don't see any code for setting the variable mentioned there.

Has anyone been able to block their website visits from Google Analytics using a cookie?

EDIT:
This seems to work https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout.  Although I don't think it was designed as I'm using it.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look like there may a good way to this besides the option below.  Adding as an answer since it does work.

This seems to work https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout.