# Does resetting your modem frequently make using Google Analytics's "Ignore IP" feature pointless

Tags: google-analytics, ip-address

Back in the Megavideo days, I'd reset my modem quite a bit to get around the viewing time restriction. As I understand it, the IP address changes each time (unless you have it set to a static IP).

That said, I'd like to exclude myself by IP from being tracked on my site through Google Analytics. Is there a way to do this given that the IP address is dynamic? Is it dynamic within a certain range?

Also, I know you can exclude yourself through cookies, but I'd like to leave that as a last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering out an IP is better for corporate users with a static address. If your IP might change then it's easier to just use a custom variable to filter out your own traffic. See: [How do you exclude yourself from Google Analytics on your website using cookies?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15552/how-do-you-exclude-yourself-from-google-analytics-on-your-website-using-cookies)

Comment: Sorry it took so long to select the best answer. I got distracted and forgot about this question. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

That's up to you to figure out. Reboot your modem and log the IP addresses assigned to you. See if they are all in the same C block. If so, you can probably filter that C block without having an effect on the accuracy of your statistics. If you IP addresses go outside of just a few C blocks then you start to run the risk of filtering out too many other users and affecting the accuracy of your statistics. This is especially true if your site attracts local users.

Comment: Haven't tested it on my modem, but I believe many ISPs assign the same IP to a client (identified by MAC address) for days at a time, based on the lease period. This is generally more efficient as it requires less changes to the client table while making sure everyone gets an IP address. And unless your modem is off at the end of the DHCP lease period, it will continue to renew the lease for the same IP for consistency.