# Block Internal Traffic from Google Analytics for Remote Team Members

Tags: google-analytics, ip-address, traffic, google-tag-manager

We are 100% remote, meaning no office. Currently I have an IP filter that blocks the IP of every single team member but this is not manageable since A) It's a pain to get everyone to send me their IP address B) It's messy to setup, C) An IP address can change and D) Several team members, including myself, tend to have different working spots during the day.

Also we've thought about using browser extensions but not everyone uses Google Chrome, some use Safari, others Edge...

What's the best way to block internal traffic for a remote team?

Comment: Just don't use your own site then there is no need for any blocking solution.

Comment: That's no good...

Comment: Are you using Google Tag Manager? I have something in mind what can help you if you use GTM

Comment: There are only three options:  1.) Block their IP address or range as you discussed above 2.) Use the [Google Analytics Opt-out Browser Add-on](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout), which is available for all major browsers 3.) Set a non-expiring cookie. The linked question has an answer containing all three, and [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15552/how-do-you-exclude-yourself-from-google-analytics-on-your-website-using-cookies?rq=1) question is specific to setting a cookie.

Comment: In the tool that you posted it says it isn't available for Microsoft Edge? Just IE 11. Also that answer is several years old now. The GA tracking code has changed since then.

Comment: We could use Google Tag Manager, what's your idea? @gintsg

Comment: @EdgarQuintero That's what Google provides, there are others obviously, but [recommendations for third-party software](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is considered off-topic here. The question & answer are still applicable regardless of updates. Please use @_user to direct comments in the future, otherwise they won't get notified.